# How to overcome maven FileNotFoundException error?

Tags: maven, centos

I installed maven on usr/share/maven and also have set path in maven.sh file.
i restart my computer and typed

**mvn -version**

and getting error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/apache-maven/conf/logging
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:264)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.configure(Launcher.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[sandip@bigdatasvn ~]$ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/apache-maven/conf/logging^C
```

Comment: I have found I get this in Eclipse. A restart fixes it.

Comment: @MarkW I found this just now and restarting Eclipse was the fix. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Maven configuration and make sure the logging file is in that path.  If you installed on /usr/share/maven, that's also not the same path as /usr/share/apache-maven.

Comment: I checked that path ..but there is no such folder.
/usr/share/apache-maven/conf/logging

Comment: Thank you it worked ..i copied the conf folder from another setup

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the epel-apache-maven repo.
(http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/)

If it is the case, do "yum update apache-maven"
and apache-maven-3.2.1-1 should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this will be the solution for everyone, but a restart fixed this problem for me (and @D-Klotz)

Answer (score 0):

Restart eclipse with this command -

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

In case you are using STS (Spring Tool Suite), restart STS with this command -

```
STS.exe -clean
```

Hope this will help :)