# FileNotFoundException when running two instances of Eclipse at the same time

Tags: eclipse

I often need to work on two (or more) workspaces at the same time, pointing on different branches. As you'll surely get from the stacktrace below, I'm running Eclipse on Windows. 
All my workspaces work perfectly when used alone.
But since I upgraded to Eclipse Oxygen, it doesn't work that much when I perform the following actions:

1. Open the first Eclipse, choose the first workspace
2. Launch a Maven (basic clean) command -> Ok
3. Open the second Eclipse, choose the second workspace
4. Launch the same Maven command from the first workspace -> Exception below

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\39\0\.cp\
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.configure(Launcher.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I can't really tell if it's the Maven plugin or Eclipse itself that throws this exception, because Maven is my only starting point (however, SVN synchronize does work properly)

Watching the content of the `C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi` directory, I can see that basically, once the second Eclipse is launched, it clears the configuration folders required for the first instance. Several of my team members have the same issue since the Oxygen upgrade.
Browsing SO and Eclipse forums, I found no related issue that is recent enough to be relevant. 
And of course, having several Eclipse folders is not the answer I'm looking to...

'Funny' thing, a colleague of mine has exactly the same problem while having both Eclipse and JasperSoft Studio (latest version, based on Eclipse) opened at the same time. So far, I couldn't reproduce it.

Any clues?

Comment: Same stack trace here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21822099/6505250

Comment: Yeah but the solution to the related problem is "restart Eclipse", which is exactly what I don't want to do, because in this case, I don't need several instances at the same time...